# Echoing text between numbers with decimals

Tags: php

I've putted a script together a bit with array's and stuff.
Now in the end, it checks for a score with checkboxes and divides it by ten.
Then with number format i round it off two 2 decimals, it looks like this.

```
$number = $score / $total;
$number = $number * 10;
$number = number_format(round($number,2),2,',','.');
echo "The number is: $number <br/>";
```

Then later on, i'm doing this.

```
if($number < 4 && $number > 0)
echo 'You're number is between zero and 4';
else if($number > 6 && $number < 4)
echo ' You're number is between 4and 6';
else if($number < 8 && $number > 6)
echo' You're number is between 6 and 8';
else if($number < 10 && $number > 8)
You're number is between 8 and 10';
```

Now, if the number is like, 0.50 or 1.50 or 2 or 5.50 it's shows the text i've provided.
However, if the number is like 4,13 or 7,85 or 9,13 it doesn't.

Searched now quite a while but can't figure it out.
Do you people see a solution?

Hope i was clear enough!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a side note: you need to escape your apostrophes in your `echo` statements. Or even better, use the correct version of the word your :)

Comment: your elseif conditions are not all correct. e.g. $number > 6 && $number < 4. 2ndly, please correct the quotes.

Comment: Haha, it was fast typed. And i'm not the best at english grammar;)
Will do the the other thing though;)

Comment: Omg, I just realised, I'm becoming a grammar troll. Spell it however you like, I dont care (look I even missed out the apostrophe in my don't back there), just make sure you escape apostrophes if you have them in single quoted strings. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<?php
$score = 7; //Example values
$total = 32;

$number = $score / $total;
$number = $number * 10;
$number = round($number,2);
echo 'The number is: ',number_format($number,2,'.',','),' <br/>';

if($number < 4 && $number > 0)
    echo 'Your number is between zero and 4';
else if($number < 6 && $number > 4)
    echo 'Your number is between 4 and 6';
else if($number < 8 && $number > 6)
    echo 'Your number is between 6 and 8';
else if($number < 10 && $number > 8)
    echo 'Your number is between 8 and 10';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Chief17.
This works after some testing, can see the difference you did.
Lesson learned:)

Answer (score 1):

The following statement will never validate `true`:

```
if($number > 6 && $number < 4)
```

Do you know any number that's higher than six and smaller than four?

The code also contains numerous syntax errors, for example:

```
echo 'You're number is between zero and 4';
```

The apostrophe needs to be escaped using a backslash:

```
echo 'You\'re number is between zero and 4';
```

Or use double quotes for strings containing apostrophes:

```
echo "You're number is between zero and 4";
```

Finally, grammar whise, `you're` should be `your` :)